# Apache NiFi combination of GenerateTableFetch and ExecuteSQLRecord duplicates data

Tags: apache-nifi

So I am using NiFi in a cluster mode, with 5 machines. My Flow starts with an **GenerateTableFetch**, executed on the **Primary Node** only. As properties, I have set the **Partition Size** equal to 4000000. The connection is the standard one for an Oracle Database, and my table is a generic table with more then 50M rows.

Now, the downstream connection (success) from **GenerateTableFetch** is linked to an **ExecuteSQLRecord**. The connection is set with the **Load Balance Strategy** = Round Robin and **Selected Prioritizers** = FIFO.

Within the ExecuteSQLRecord, I have configured the following properties: **Use Avro Logical Type** = true, **Max Rows Per Flow File** = 4000000, **Output Batch Size** = 5, **Set Auto Commit** = true. When it comes to scheduling, I have 7 **Concurrent Tasks** and All nodes as **Execution**.

Once the data is converted into AVRO/Parquet (tried with both), I load them into a GCP Bucket/AWS S3. Afterwards, I load the data into their data warehouse service.
The problem is that when I check my data, even though I have the same number of rows like in the Source Table, the data is not the same. I have plenty of duplicate rows and I managed to pin point the one causing the duplication of data: ExecuteSQLRecord. But I cannot figure why this is happening nor how I can solve it.

From GenerateTableFetch I send to ExecuteSQLRecord FF which looks like the below lines. What I have noticed though is that they get grouped by in a strange manner and the fragment.index is like 1, 18, 9, 12, 5 for the first execution and so on, meaning that they are not in order.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1 FETCH NEXT 4000000 ROWS ONLY
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1 OFFSET 4000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4000000 ROWS ONLY
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1 OFFSET 8000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4000000 ROWS ONLY
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1 OFFSET 12000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4000000 ROWS ONLY
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1 OFFSET 16000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4000000 ROWS ONLY
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 1=1 OFFSET 20000000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4000000 ROWS ONLY
```

Has anybody else struggled with a similar issue? And if so, did you manage to find a solution?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use custom order by to have an id column from source sorting the data over which the fetch can go in an iterative manner, without order by property in GenerateTableFetch causes duplicated. use an id or Pkey column in the order by property to avoid duplicates